# Trying Spring MVC with Hibernate integration for the first time, getting error 505

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Eclipse IDE using Spring MVC with Hibernate orm. All the details along with the errors shown in browser and console are also given below

Error shown in internalbrowser

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


Root Cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    
Root Cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    
Root Cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

error displayed in console:

```
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
Sep 01, 2020 3:40:54 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver])
ERROR: Unable obtain JDBC Connection
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1136)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver])
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2397)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:855)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1327)
    

Hibernate: drop table MYDept cascade constraints
framework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver])
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2397)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:855)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1327)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    
Sep 01, 2020 3:40:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
Sep 01, 2020 3:40:55 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Sep 01, 2020 3:40:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1136)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver])
    
Sep 01, 2020 3:40:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1136)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver])
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2397)
    

Sep 01, 2020 3:40:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [dispatcher]
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver])
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Department Actions</h2>
<a href="PreInsertDepartment">Insert Department</a>
</body>
</html>
```

DepartmentController.java

```
package com.wipro.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.wipro.bean.Department;
import com.wipro.dao.DepartmentDao;

@Controller
public class DepartmentController {

@Autowired
DepartmentDao dao;

@RequestMapping("PreInsertDepartment")
public ModelAndView preInsert() {
Department department = new Department();
department.setDeptno(dao.getDepartmentId());
ModelAndView mv = new
ModelAndView("InsertDepartment","department",department);
return mv;
}
@RequestMapping("InsertDepartment")
public ModelAndView insertDepartment(@ModelAttribute("department") Department dept) {
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("result","department",dept);
if(dao.insertDepatment(dept))
    mv.addObject("msg", "Inserted Successfully");
    else
    mv.addObject("msg", "Insert Failed");
    return mv;
    }
    }
```

Department.java

```
package com.wipro.bean;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="MYDept")
public class Department {
    @Id
    private int deptno;
    @Column(length = 10)
    private String dname;
    @Column(length = 10)
    private String loc;
    
    
    public Department() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Department(int deptno, String dname, String loc) {
        super();
        this.deptno = deptno;
        this.dname = dname;
        this.loc = loc;
    }
    public int getDeptno() {
        return deptno;
    }
    public void setDeptno(int deptno) {
        this.deptno = deptno;
    }
    public String getDname() {
        return dname;
    }
    public void setDname(String dname) {
        this.dname = dname;
    }
    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }
    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Department [deptno=" + deptno + ", dname=" + dname + ", loc=" + loc + "]";
    }
    
    

}
```

DepartmentDao.java

```
package com.wipro.dao;
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.wipro.bean.Department;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class DepartmentDao {
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Autowired
HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public int getDepartmentId() {
int id=0;
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Query<Department> qry = session.createQuery("Select max(d.deptno) from Department d");
List l=qry.list();
System.out.println("L value"+l + " : " );
if(l!=null && l.size()>0)
{
Object b=l.get(0);
if(b!=null)
    id=(Integer) b;
    }
    session.close();
    return id+10;
    }

    public boolean insertDepatment(Department department) {
    hibernateTemplate.persist(department);
    return true;
    }
    }
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wipro" />
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Including the bean for View Resolver -->
<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
<value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>

</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName"
value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
<property name="url"
value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
<property name="username" value="system" />
<property name="password" value="oracle" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop
key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
</props>
</property>
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.wipro.bean" />
</bean>
<bean id="hibernateTemplate"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
 </bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

InsertDepartment.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<sp:form action="InsertDepartment" method="post" modelAttribute="department">
Enter Department No: <sp:input path="deptno" />
Enter Department Name : <sp:input path="dname"/>
Enter Department Location : <sp:input path="loc" />
<input type="submit"/>
</sp:form>

</body>
</html>
```

result.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
${msg}
Department [ ${department.deptno } , ${department.dname } , ${department.loc } ] 
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml
The ojdbc dependency used installs the required ojdbc jar in maven dependencies ok.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wipro</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVCwithHibernate</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMVCwithHibernate Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- dependencies required for Hibernate ORM Integration -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.4.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
<version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
    <version>19.7.0.0</version>
</dependency>

    
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVCwithHibernate</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to use Oracle JDBC driver `ojdbc10` on the Java 8, which is not supported. You can either:

- switch to Java 10 or higher
- downgrade the JDBC driver to `ojdbc8`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```